# FaultTolerant implementation for DB connection loss

Tags: java, mysql

Imagine that the DB is down and your application is not able to execute queries that have crucial data. You have to execute those queries when DB is up and connection is established again.

Is it the only way to collect those thousands of preparedStatements in aa collection and execute them when DB connection is back? What if those query executions cause a load on DB and negatively effects the application performance?

Comment: you could use some message queue (or even temp files) to persist all open queries. When the db is back online, you can execute the queries at a rate you can determine yourself, depending on your environment. That would not be fault tolerant per se, it would just be a caching mechanism and would not last forever, at some point the message queue would be full and your application would have to stop processing incoming queries.

Comment: I agree with you @DirkTrilsbeek . Do you have any suggestion to make it fault tolerant?

Comment: you could use a database cluster or virtualization features. "Fault tolerance" is a broad term and you have to think about which scenarios you want to cover. Hardware failures can be mitigated by having a database cluster spreading several hardware systems. If your DB is already in a virtualized environment, there may be a virtualization feature like VMware Fault Tolerance available to you that can help you increasing your database uptime. Maybe even in combination with the previously mentioned queue, that should give you a pretty good service availability.

Comment: Thanks @DirkTrilsbeek